# How to create a script for insert data on redis

Tags: shell, redis

I need to create a .sh file to run insert commands in redis, but redis running on docker container. How can I do this?

A file that runs something like:

```
redis-cli

# =============================  MOC  0111:C5303391  =============================

HSET "MOC  0111:C5303391" MOC "MOC  0111" H_W "teste" H_Y "teste" F "teste"
```

Answer (score 0):

This would pipe the commands from the file into the container (commands.txt is your file):

```
# start Redis container if not already started
docker run -d --name rediscontainer redis

# pipe commands to the container
cat commands.txt | docker exec -i rediscontainer bash
```

It would still complain about the `# ======` comment line as it would attempt to execute it inside redis-cli.

If you can remove the first two lines and leave only redis commands in the file, then switch to:

```
cat commands.txt | docker exec -i rediscontainer redis-cli
```

You can also try it in a `redis-cli --pipe` mode, which gives you a summary of errors/successful commands:

```
cat commands.txt | docker exec -i rediscontainer redis-cli --pipe
```

See: https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert for the reference. Example above just combine these with docker commands.